# asp.net mvc icon render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, icons, devexpress, render

I want to show icon that associated with file type. Something like this 
[image]

But background is black (in firefox and IE), in chrome it is transparent, and its good. 
[image]

My controller

```
 public ActionResult GetFileTypeIcon(string fileName)
        {
            var photo = PhotoModel.GetFileTypeIcon(fileName);

            if (photo == null)
            {
                return File(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/nofile.png"), "image/png");
            }

            var stream = new MemoryStream(photo);


            return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/bmp");
        }
```

I also try to convert icon to png but than quality of image is very bad.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(photo);

            var iconStream = new MemoryStream();

            Image.FromStream(stream).Save(iconStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
```

[image]

view (i use devexpress grid)

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "attachmentsGrid";

    settings.Columns.Add(col =>
    {
        col.Caption = "Назва";

        col.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<table><tr><td>");

            //Html.DevExpress().BinaryImage(imageSettings =>
            //{
            //    imageSettings.Width = 16;
            //    imageSettings.Height = 16;
            //}).Bind(PhotoModel.GetFileTypeIcon(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "_name").ToString())).Render();
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<img height=\"16px\" width=\"16px\" src=\"" + Url.Action("GetFileTypeIcon", "Photo", new { fileName = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "_name").ToString() }) + "\" alt=\"image\" />");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</td><td>");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("&nbsp&nbsp");
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                 Html.ActionLink(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "_name").ToString(), "Download", new { Link = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "_link"), Name = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "_name") }));
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</td></tr></table>");
        });
    });
```

and method thats return image as byte array. RegisteredFileType.ExtractIconFromFile - returns an Icon.

```
public static byte[] GetFileTypeIcon(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] array;
                var fileType = filename.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
                fileType = "." + fileType.ToLower();
                string fileAndParam = (_iconsInfo[fileType]).ToString();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileAndParam))
                    return null;

                var icon = RegisteredFileType.ExtractIconFromFile(fileAndParam, false);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    icon.ToBitmap().Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    array = ms.ToArray();
                }

                return array;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
```

i am change methhod GetFileTypeInfo: now it returns Icon

```
 var icon = RegisteredFileType.ExtractIconFromFile(fileAndParam, false);
                return icon;
```

And controller

```
public ActionResult GetFileTypeIcon(string fileName)
        {
            var photo = PhotoModel.GetFileTypeIcon(fileName);

            if (photo == null)
            {
                return File(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/nofile.png"), "image/png");
            }

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            photo.ToBitmap().Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


            var iconStream = new MemoryStream();

            Image.FromStream(stream).Save(iconStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
        }
```

Now its render good in chrome , firefox, safari and opera, but in <s>die IE</s> IE its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like image bolder issue. can you try to add `img { border: 0; }` to your site.css file to see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but when you return your image in the first example the mimetype is wrong. You should return `"image/png"` instead. Bitmaps don't support transparency, which would explain why the icons become non-transparent.

Comment: i have edited my question, if i return as "image/png" result is also bad.

Comment: Its seems a little strange, but icons for word or excell apps render good in IE too. I find that only chrome icon for .htm file render bad.